# How to make the pointer glide on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, macbook, touchpad

I just moved from Dos To Mac. On my old laptop I could configure the touchpad to "glide" with the synaptic driver. That is the pointer would continue to move a bit after I lift my moving finger off the touchpad. Is there a way to achieve the same thing on Mac OS X? It kind of simulates a track-ball.

Comment: Why would you want a gliding effect? Is it because the mouse cursor moves too slow?

Comment: I have mobility issues. Speeding up the pointer makes things worse for me. But it's easy for me to make little flicks. I need the pointer slow for more accuracy.

Comment: I think none of the better known 3rd party mouse/trackpad utilities (USB Overdrive, Steermouse, BetterTouchTool, Jitouch, MagicPrefs) do this, but they might be worth a closer look to be sure. BTT Remote supports inertial pointer movement according to its website, so maybe as a feature request for BTT...?

Comment: Yes, I found BTT and put in a feature request. Thanks.

Comment: Look on the Mac App store- most likely there is a software on there that can do this.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't anything. BTT has it with the BTT Remote, but that only works via iphone/ipad, not the touchpad.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to find a solution to this problem for years now. There are three answers to this question, and none will make you happy:

1. **Create custom touchpad drivers yourself**

   Sadly, this is the only sure way at the moment to get inertial pointer on OS X.
2. **Create an incentive for somebody else to create custom drivers**

   Send emails to BTT, Overdrive, etc. Comment on blogs that talk about inertial pointer on OSX. Talk about it on Twitter. Upvote posts about it on StackOverflow.
3. **Buy a trackball**

   Trackballs have natural inertia. You can flick the ball and it will keep gliding as the ball decelerates.

**PS. Here's a way to try what inertial pointer on OSX would feel like.**

There is a bug in OSX 10.8 that can trigger *inertial-like* behaviour.

1. Grab a window by touching the **window header** using **three fingers** on the touchpad.
2. Move the window just a bit while keeping all three fingers on the touchpad.
3. Now, use a fourth finger to flick the window around.

Comment: I spoke with the BTT developer and he says it's difficult, if not impossible. But he's mentioned he'll try. Hopefully he can come up with something.

Comment: Regarding the so called bug, I cannot reproduce it on my iMac (with Magic Trackpad and OSX 10.8.4), but I can do something similar: doing steps 1 and 2, and then moving only 1 of the 3 fingers that I used to start the move operation (you can even remove it from the trackpad, provided that you do not remove the other 2).